# Setting TMediaPlayer volume doesn't work on iOS Device and Simulator in Delphi XE Mobile Application

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe6

I am using TMediaPlayer without control in my Delphi XE5 Firemonkey mobile application,
Setting volume is not working on iOS device and simulator, but it works on Abdroid, any idea?

```
MusicMediaPlayer := TMediaplayer.Create(nil);
MusicMediaPlayer.FileName := TmpFile;
MusicMediaPlayer.Play;
if IsMusicOn then
    MusicMediaPlayer.Volume := 0.03
else
    MusicMediaPlayer.Volume := 0;
```

With above code the file is played with maximum volume level even when it is 0.

Comment: This is still the case in Delphi XE6 update 1.